# let android mediaPlayer loops differently

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a video I want to loop in android, I have set the

```
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

but every time when it loops, I want to perform something, like making a toast showing how many times it's looped or detecting the current rotation and change a looping video if  rotation has changed.

how can I do it?

Comment: With an [`onCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)?

Comment: Yes i think OnCompletionListener is the best way to solve it.